# Alternatives to Google Ads and Facebook Ads

Tags: google-ads-api, facebook-ads

I'm working with Google Ads and Facebook Ads and I would like to test more services to compare the results.

Also I would like to know if you know any service that generates campaigns easily for people without experience.

Comment: You can use InMobi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check Bing Ads, Adroll, Amazon ads, Outbrain, Linkedin Ads, Instagram Ads...

Now with Google Ads you have Inteligent Campaigns, easy to use.